# Ruby code that doesn't work

Tags: ruby, if-statement

This is an [Euler Project Number 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1).

```
sum = 0
array = []

for num in 1...1000
    if num % 3 === 0
        sum = sum + num
        array.push(num)
    end
    if num % 5 === 0
        sum = sum + num
        array.push(num)
    end
end

#puts array
puts sum
```

When I run the program with `10` as the range, I get the correct input, but when I use `1000`, my answer is `266333`, whereas the correct answer is `266138` according to the answer cheat. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you need an `elsif` instead of two `if` statements. Currently you have some numbers which are divisible by both 3 AND 5, that are being added to the total sum twice.

```
for num in 1...1000
    if num % 3 === 0
        sum = sum + num
        array.push(num)
    elsif num % 5 === 0
        sum = sum + num
        array.push(num)
    end
end
```

or a better way:

```
for num in 1...1000
    if num % 3 == 0 || num % 5 == 0
        sum = sum + num
        array.push(num)
    end
end
```

Comment: `(1...1000).select {|n| (n%3).zero? || (n%5).zero? }.inject(:+)`

Comment: @JörgWMittag: In theory, it's *possible* to do all the Project Euler problems as single expressions. Might be tricky, though!

Comment: You can also do `case 0; when num % 3, num % 5; ... end`.